# Concordance/Word List Maker software

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm looking for word list maker software that I can use to create a list of words that I've learned in French. It would allow me to open a text file and only highlight the words that are not part of my master list already, so that I wouldn't be repeating the work I'd already done.

Any ideas on (free) software that does this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this extremely basic CodePen](https://codepen.io/lukesawczak/full/xxGybMB) I whipped up :)

More for fun / a doorstop than anything, but if you do use it, note that the dictionary is just a cookie that can easily be cleared by accident, so you might want to keep a separate copy as a backup.

[image: demonstration of word highlighter]